# Double image slider portfolio

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have been searching everywhere now but can't seem to find anything.

I'm making a portfolio website for a photograph and he has this special gallery slider that he really wants so I asking for help here instead.

The website that he wants to have a image gallery look-a-like is from this one: http://www.dnamodels.com

The top one with the play and pause icon.
So if anyone know how to do something like this I would really appreciate any help!

And non-wordpress.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour] and see the [help/on-topic]. Right now, Your question is not really suitable for [so], as it is not sufficiently specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you know some jquery you can try flexslider. It gives you an easy way to build your own slider and gives you some functions to control it, like animation, next, prev, etc..

you can see examples here: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly simple. Here is one way to go:

1. On your html file create a UL with LI elements containing the images that you want to present (could be in IMG tags or as background images to the LI element).
2. Create some kind of a counter in order to know the total number of images you have in the gallery and also in order to give a unique id to each LI element / gallery image.
3. With css make each of the LI elements an absolute positioned element filling the entire container but displayed none (or visible hidden / opacity 0 with a nice transition property if you want it to fade nicely like in the example)
4. Create an "active" css class making the LI that has it to visible and attach it to your first LI element in the gallery
5. Create a JS function with an interval - incrementing a counter variable every few seconds (or reseting it if it equals to the total number of elements), removing the active class from all LI elements in your gallery and adding the active class to the element with the ID matching your variable value.
6. Bind a click event to your gallery that is switching between calling the above function (playing the gallery) and clearing the interval that is running in the function (pausing the gallery). In order to the change the cursor icon to play or pause icons - use addClass/removeClass with classes that are using the "cursor: url(xxx/yyy.png), auto".
7. Run the play function on document ready.